# Problem with the Testing dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-testing

It was first time testing on the Android IDE  so I was following this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/testing-room-database-in-android-using-junit/)

I was trying to test the database by inserting the element into database and check if the database contains the element.

Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\edita\AndroidStudioProjects\PlantManagement\app\src\test\java\com\example\plantmanagement\DatabaseTest.kt: (8, 17): Unresolved reference: test
C:\Users\edita\AndroidStudioProjects\PlantManagement\app\src\test\java\com\example\plantmanagement\DatabaseTest.kt: (7, 17): Unresolved reference: test
C:\Users\edita\AndroidStudioProjects\PlantManagement\app\src\test\java\com\example\plantmanagement\DatabaseTest.kt: (12, 19): Unresolved reference: common
C:\Users\edita\AndroidStudioProjects\PlantManagement\app\src\test\java\com\example\plantmanagement\DatabaseTest.kt: (23, 10): Unresolved reference: AndroidJUnit4
C:\Users\edita\AndroidStudioProjects\PlantManagement\app\src\test\java\com\example\plantmanagement\DatabaseTest.kt: (30, 23): Unresolved reference: ApplicationProvider
C:\Users\edita\AndroidStudioProjects\PlantManagement\app\src\test\java\com\example\plantmanagement\DatabaseTest.kt: (58, 6): Unresolved reference: assertThat
```

Here is my build gradle file:

```js
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.plantmanagement"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
    

}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    //Room database
    implementation "androidx.room:room-common:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1'


    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
    //coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2'
    //Lifecycle
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.2.0"
    //Viewmodel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    //LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"
    //ui
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    //navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    //views
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    //testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.6"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.2"
    androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.4"
    androidTestImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.5.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.2"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.3.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.3.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'

}
```

I have tried `Invalidate Caches/Restarts`

I also tried replacing `testImplementantion` to `androidTestImplementation`

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: First hurdle : You probably need your tests in the `androidTest` folder, not `test` - you are tring to run instrumented tests, these should be done using the Android SDK Runtime environment not Java JDK runtime. Ref : https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests

Comment: @Mark Keen I will try doing that.

Comment: @MarkKeen It's indeed got rid of alot of error.